# How to get the ints values from bytes data type from a wave file using the wave library

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working with some wave 24-bits wave file.

I used the "wavread" function from here: https://gist.github.com/WarrenWeckesser/7461781.

The next code is an example:

Example code

```
audio1 = wave.open('13file4.wav')

rate = audio1.getframerate()
nchannels = audio1.getnchannels()
sampwidth = audio1.getsampwidth()
nframes = audio1.getnframes() #.shape[0]
data = audio1.readframes(nframes)
audio1.close()
```

In "data" you can find something like this: b'\x00\x00\xffm'

Where \x00,\x00 and \xffm are in hex format.

Is there any way to get each of these values separately and transform them in int values?

I know there is the int.from_bytes function, but I can not get each value from the data file.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) object, and, as stated in the documentation:

> While bytes literals and representations are based on ASCII text,
>   bytes objects actually behave like immutable sequences of integers

So, you can access any of the bytes by indexing, you'll get an integer:

```
data = b'\x00\x00\xffm'

print(data[2])
# 255
```

or you can turn it all into a real list of integers:

```
print(list(data))
# [0, 0, 255, 109]
```